# Spark mapPartitions vs transient lazy val

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, partition, transient

I was wondering what is the different of using sparks `mapPartitions` functionality vs transient lazy val.
Since each partition is basically running on a different node a single instance of transient lazy val will be created on each nod (assuming its in an object).

For example:

```
class NotSerializable(v: Int) {
  def foo(a: Int) = ???
}

object OnePerPartition {
  @transient lazy val obj: NotSerializable = new NotSerializable(10)
}

object Test extends App{
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000)

    rdd.map(OnePerPartition.obj.foo)

    // ---------- VS ----------

    rdd.mapPartitions(itr => {
      val obj = new NotSerializable(10)
      itr.map(obj.foo)
    })
}
```

One might ask why would you even want it...  
I would like to create a general container notion for running my logic on any generic collection implementation (`RDD`, `List`, `scalding pipe`, etc.)
All of them have a notion of "map", but `mapPartition` is unique for `spark`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you don't need `transient` `lazy` here. Using `object` wrapper is enough to make this work and you can actually write this as:

```scala
object OnePerExecutor {
  val obj: NotSerializable = new NotSerializable(10)
}
```

There is a fundamental difference between the object wrapper and initializing `NotSerializable` inside `mapPartitions`. This:

```scala
rdd.mapPartitions(iter => {
  val ns = NotSerializable(1)
  ???
})
```

creates a single `NotSerializable` instance per partition.

Object wrapper from the other hand, creates a single `NotSerializable` instance for each executor JVM. As a result this instance:

- Can be used to process multiple partitions.
- Can be accessed simultaneously by multiple executor threads.
- Has lifespan exceeding function call where it is used.

It means it should be thread safe and any method calls should be side effects free.